# How to deal with exception in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have an async method in Windows Phone 8.1, which need to download a file from the web. Of course if there is no internet connection, it can't do. How Can I face this problem. The method is this one:

```
public async Task<string> getJson(Uri url)
    {
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            return jsonString;
        }
        else
        {
            await new MessageDialog("No internet connection is avaliable. Please check it !").ShowAsync();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Should I add the check of the internet connection, before calling the getJSon(Uri url); method ? In this case I have to re-write those lines of code in each method, which require the getJson(Uri url); and I prefer not to do this.

**UPDATE**

The code I wrote doesn't work, because the application crashes in case there is no Internet connection. The solution, which I don't like is something like this:

```
private async void change(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof("Page with async method"));
        }
        else
        {
             await new MessageDialog("No internet connection is avaliable. Please check it !").ShowAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint, and sorry If I was not able to let you understand completely the situation. I modify the question. I hope you will understand better !

Comment: Why don't you debug using breakpoints and find where is the problem. Then post the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the internet connection is ok, but it still might come unavailable immediately after you've done the check.

The correct solution is to catch the exception and deal with it:

```
public async Task<string> getJson(Uri url)
{        
    bool error = false;
    if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {         
       try
       {
           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           string jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
           return jsonString;
       }
       catch(Exception) // a more specific exception would be better
       {
           error = true;
       }
    }
    else
    {
        error = true;     
    }

    if (error)
    {
        await new MessageDialog("No internet connection is avaliable. Please check it !").ShowAsync();
        return "";
    }
}
```

I personally would handle the exception on a higher level (ie. the caller of `getJson()`)

Comment: That's a very good explanation ! So your hint is before I call the method async, I check the connection, isn't it ?

Comment: the code I provided already checks that, so you don't need to do it again

Comment: Yes I know it,. What I was saying, it about your best approach. It is better to check the method before invoke it, isn't it ?